# How to safely try KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments

There's a way to safely try KDE on top of an Ubuntu installation, keeping the possibility to revert the changes in case I dislike how it runs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The absolute safest way to do that is to install it on a separate partition, but that's probably more work than you need.
What I'd recommend is to install Kubuntu. I'm not sure if that's really what you meant when you said "KDE on top of an Ubuntu installation", but Kubuntu is little more than KDE+Ubuntu. Just do:

> sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop [image: Install Kubuntu]

on any terminal window (it will install a ton of kde packages). By the end, you'll get prompted if you want to use gdm or kdm as login manager. It's OK to choose either one, but kdm will give you the full Kubuntu experience.

Next time you boot, just before logging in, choose KDE as your session manager. It will use the same `$HOME` and the same root folder, and thus you'll still have all the same programs installed, and their respective settings will be kept. I might be wrong, but I think only the settings stored under `~/.gnome2/` won't be loaded by KDE (they *are* gnome settings after all).

---

Finally, you don't really need to remove KDE after that. You can keep using gnome regularly, and never choose KDE again in the session manager. If, for some reason, you *do* want to really remove KDE (maybe you need to free up space), here's what you do:

> sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop

kubuntu-desktop is a dummy package (you'll notice the removal process will be quick), removing this package will make apt consider all of the kde packages as unnecessary (since they were brought along by this one), so just do:

> sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

If you chose to keep gdm as your login manager, you can stop here. If you happened to choose kdm as your login manager back in the first step, you'll have to **either** reinstall gdm (it's technically already installed, so you can just reconfigure it if you know how) `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm` **or** reinstall kdm again `sudo apt-get install kdm`.

---

**EDIT** According to @AnwarShah the method above for removing Kubuntu doesn't actually work. I don't have an Ubuntu machine on which to test that right now, so I'll just provide an alternative method.

The command provided in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17221/1012), *should* purge all traces of kde from your system. **Before** running it you should read all of the packages and make sure none of them had been previously installed by you! Make sure to remove the name of any packages you want to keep. 
*(Also, I haven't read through all of those packages, so I can't garantee anything regarding the commands effectiveness.)*

Alternatively, you could keept track of all packages installed when you install `kubuntu-desktop`, and then just do `apt-get purge` on these packages. This requires the forethought of copying the list of packages back when you installed `kubuntu-desktop` (and remembering where you saved it), but it's a little safer to do.

Comment: Thank you so much: how do I keep track of every packages that come with kubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @dag729: When you perform that first command, apt-get will list all packages that will get installed and ask for your confirmation. Copy them somewhere.

Comment: Usually, after "apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop", you can run "apt-get autoremove --purge" to remove everything else it pulled in.

Comment: @kees: I thought about that, but wouldn't that remove kdm as well (thus causing issues on login)?

Comment: Perhaps, though `gdm` should still be there.  If not, try following it with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to make sure it had everything Gnome needs.

Comment: gdm will certainly still be there, but it will need to be reconfigured (or reinstalled) in case kdm is removed. I'll edit the answer with your method.

Comment: @BruceConnor.I test it and never works. Did you actually test it in your machine ?. It only removes `kubuntu-desktop` and after the second command nothing happens. I happens because `kubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage and in the case of metapackage, apt does not remove other packages which this metapackage brought.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I just trusted @KeesCook comment. =) From reading the manpage it seems like it should work. I'll add an extra method anyway.

Comment: @BruceConnor, Thanks that you notice it, But the problem with second method is it is dependent on the version of Ubuntu, (actually Kubuntu, since the default packages installed by `kubuntu-desktop` may change. Anyway, It will helps users.

Answer (score 8):

Just install it...

> sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop [image: Install Kubuntu]

At login (after entering your username) you can select which one you want to boot (gnome/kde/xfce/...) so it's always possible to go back to gnome, even without rebooting.

Comment: That works. Uninstalling the parts if you don't like it is not quite as straightforward, but can be done.

Comment: I'd also add a new user just for testing KDE so it doesn't clutter up your existing $home with KDE configuration files. If you like KDE, fine, just use your normal user with the KDE session. If you don't like it, your profile hasn't been affected in any way.

Comment: @frabjous: Though if you mark everything kubuntu-desktop requires as an automatic (instead of manual) install, e.g. through aptitude, that should be much easier.

Comment: Creating a different user for testing purposes is in my opinion the best solution.

Comment: Uninstalling is not that easy. I tried it in natty, oneiric, and now in precise. It never works. Because dependents packages are never marks as automatically installed. This can give you a hint. `apt-config dump`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde can help you.

Just install Kubuntu Plasma Desktop system on your computer through the software center.

To uninstall it follow the instructions given here:

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a VM?

Or try a Live CD.

Comment: Not an option, because I want to see how it works on the same conditions as gnome: I know how it is (I used kde back in karmic), but I want to try it with this new hardware and configurations.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well a Live CD would work as well.

Comment: @Mitch "Run it in a VM or try a live CD" is definitely an **answer** to how to safely try a wide variety of software, *including* KDE. Answers don't become comments *just* by being short. If this were posted as a comment, I'd comment requesting that the author make it into an answer.

Answer (score -3):

My choice (since refurbished systems are really cheap ~ $200) build a test-bench with these! I have several test-bench systems that I install on - before installing or upgrading critical systems. I've tried the live CD, but I prefer the test-bench.

Comment: The poster is specifically wanting to see how it runs on his system.

Comment: yes - but you don't experiment in a production environment (or if there is a fear you may lose data.

Comment: I use this standard - even on LTS upgrades.