# kubuntu-desktop took over everything

Tags: unity, kubuntu

I installed kubuntu-desktop via software centre but now everything is messed up in unity. As if the theme was changed but it's still "Ambiance" (the default). It even affects LXDE.
For example...

- Icon theme was changed to some other icon theme.
  [image: Icons]
- Some fonts are different like In Google chrome, fonts like "Hardware Insights Juju..." aren't supposed to be that thin. Also in the indicators' menus; you see it's not even readable and the icon for the language (that looks like this --> [EN] ) is missing.
  [image: Fonts]
- Notifications look like kubuntu's.
- Double click to maximize doesn't work any more. It glitches in a weird way. Also there's a bug when switching workspaces but it's hard for me to explain.
- Grub has a black background now.
- after grub, there should appear "Ubuntu" with 5 dots below it. Instead appears "Kubuntu" flashing.
- Who knows what else would I discover :/

What I want: A clean Unity desktop. A brand new one. And I want grub back to its old look. I tried to reinstall unity but it doesn't work. It only uninstalls a few megabytes leaving behind loads of dependencies which really matter and nothing gets fixed. I like kde as long as it doesn't mess things up. Can someone please tell me how to reinstall it or at least any workaround to all those problems though I **really really** don't prefer this.

I've tried this Q&A but no joy:

- [Ubuntu is kde styled after install AND removal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225600/ubuntu-is-kde-styled-after-install-and-removal)

I've tried to reset my Unity configuration using this Q&A but this also didnt work:

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: Or search this site for remove kubuntu

Comment: I have edited out some impolite comments and nominated the question for reopening. I feel your pain, restoring everything back after a *-desktop install is possible but not usually easy. I hope that you find an answer.

Comment: Not an answer, but IMHO reinstalling should be easier.

Comment: ahhh I'm sorry I got mad guys I'm really sorry. Specially to you @bodhi.zazen I'm so so so sorry and I was pretty rude. I just need to fix my system quick and I haven't already :'(

Comment: @JavierRivera I thought about reinstalling but this would take even more time; I have to reinstall my programs and would risk losing files. thanks for the advice

Comment: I got exactly the same problem after installing Kubuntu desktop on Ubuntu 14.04, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/507814/strange-icon-in-unity-top-menu-bar-after-installing-kde . Any luck with solving this @MinaMichael ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland sadly no :( I gave up and reinstalled my system which was awful :( I really hope _you_ find a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Very few of the unity configuration applications work any more.  Can't change desktop background, menues are seriously trashed.  I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer probably comes too late but I was just using these answers to find out the solution to the same issue and ran into this:

[Clean removal of KDE 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17202/clean-removal-of-kde-4)

From there I found this website with a one-step-shopping solution for clean ubuntu restoration:

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-ubuntu/

My version was 14.04 and that command works perfectly for me. It removed some software I installed on ubuntu before the installation of KDE but I wouldn't mind reinstall these software since now I have a pure(at least as far as what I see) ubuntu to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: after installing kubuntu-desktop, many of my unity settings were seriously messed up.  I moved all the config files, and restored them from backup.  In my home directory:

```
mv .gnome .XXgnome
mv .gnome2 .XXgnome2
mv .config .XXconfig
mv .local .XXlocal
cd /my/backup/location
cp -rp .gnome .gnome2 .config .local ~
```

I didn't bother to find out which of these kde had infected.  After a logout/login cycle, most of my unity functions are back, can I can be productive again.  The GUI widgets in most applications look kde-ish, but at least now the system fonts make sense again.  I can't tell if this is a qt or gtk configuration issue.

None of this fixed my problem that I could not change the desktop image, even after trying with `shotwell`, `gsettings`, the unity settings panel... What eventually solved that part was turning on "icons on desktop" in the gnome tweak tool.  It doesn't matter that I have all the icons turned off, "icons on desktop" has to be enabled, or nothing will change the desktop image.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, last night installed kubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04 and the language icon dissapeared and menuitems style was changed.
Things that I tried:

- System config theme setted again to Ambiance, improved some things.
- Resetting unity: unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity (No visible change).
- Edit the file located at: $HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini (this was the final solution).

The changes made to settings.ini:

gtk-theme-name=**Ambiance** (changed from value **okygen-gtk**)
gtk-icon-theme-name=**Ambiance** (changed from value **oxygen**)

Finally login into Unity again and the problem was solved. The best part is that the change is persistent, so Unity and KDE keeps their respectives styles.

Comment: This fixed unity and the icons, but chrome and all file dialogs were still kde-themed. This answer fixed those: http://askubuntu.com/a/225652