# Strange icon in Unity top menu bar after installing KDE

Tags: unity, 14.04, kubuntu

After installing Kubuntu (I am using Ubuntu 14.04), it seems that a lot of fonts disappeared and a strange icon appeared in the top menu bar in Unity. I think it is the keyboard layout icon that has turned into a red circle.

What does this mean?

**Edit:** This question: [kubuntu-desktop took over everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487815/kubuntu-desktop-took-over-everything), illustrate the same problem:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the icon that Ubuntu displays when he's not able to find the correct one defined for this particular service.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather; you no longer have an icon available for your keyboard layout selection icon. It was likely purged when you installed the kubuntu package, but I do not know for sure. I would suggest installing kubuntu natively from an ISO next time, then doing it via a package; I have these sorts of issues too from time to time when I look to install the gnome or xfce desktops environments. My experience says it is best to avoid multiple desktop environments on a single machine.

Comment: Yeah.. bad luck.. But I would like to have the possibility to switch between Unity and KDE at login.. See this question also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/487815/kubuntu-desktop-took-over-everything

Comment: You can switch at login.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `.kde`;`.gconf`;`.config` hidden in your home folder. Press `Ctrl-H` to show them and then relogin. Remember every time you log into KDE Plasma, it will automatically restore these folders, which are required for KDE to work, so before you logout of KDE, delete them again if you want to use unity after that.