# Mysterious icon after kubuntu... which app?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, icons

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I made the mistake of apt-get installing kubuntu-desktop, and removing it. I've solved all visible problems, apart from a missing icon in the top right panel. This is similar to the issue mentioned in [Strange icon in Unity top menu bar after installing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507814/strange-icon-in-unity-top-menu-bar-after-installing-kde) . The icon I'm seeing is the one with the red-circle-in-the-box thing. I've tried the steps mentioned, and also tried to figure out which app is causing it by turning off things via unity tweak tool... and it appears it's not a built in one. If I click the weird icon, I get a pop up menu, but with no entries. Is there a way to figure out which application the icon is for? Is there a list somewhere?

I even reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, but to no avail.

Comment: It's a default icon that is showed then the proper icon can not be found. Several apps suffer from this.

Comment: Yes...except it wasn't there before I went through the kubuntu-desktop install. I'm trying to figure out which app is causing the issue. The menu I get when I click it is empty, and the icon isn't "doing" anything, it seems.

Comment: Kill all suspect processes one by one?

Comment: Brilliant! It was klipper.

Comment: Worked for me too. Very annoying, but harmless :) .

Answer (score 1):

As Jos mentioned, I checked all the processes running, and killing klipper solved the issue. It seems that removing kubuntu-desktop leaves behind klipper in startup applications, which creates the icon in the panel, but it doesn't do anything. Removing it from the start up applications solved the issue.